# OSError in os.wait in python

Tags: python, operating-system, fork

Hi I m trying to execute small code in python , it is giving OS error.

```
>>> import os
>>> def child():
...     pid = os.fork()
...     if not pid:
...             for i in range(5):
...                     print i
...     return os.wait()
...
>>> child()
0
1
2
3
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in child
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

I m not able to figure out why it is giving OSError. I googled it and it is noted as bug for python 2.6 or before. I'm using python2.7.

Comment: hi it is ubuntu-server edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an else. Thus, you are calling `os.wait()` in children processes (who have no children of their own, hence the error).

Corrected code below:

```
import os
def child():
    pid = os.fork()
    if not pid:
            for i in range(5):
                    print i
    else:
        return os.wait()

child()
```

Comment: hi this works. But i m not able to understand the error cause. will you please elaborate?

Comment: Read more about multi process programming. (For example: http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~ysong/cs160/lab1/multiprocess.html, http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/multi-process/multi-process.html)
When you fork, a child process is created, which is identical to parent. Except for a single difference - return value of the fork function. Child gets 0 and parent gets child's PID. However, when any process ends, it has to pass its return value to its parent. Parent process can read it using `wait` function. If a process doesn't have any children, it is pointless to call wait, giving an error.